# Snowflake getting yearmonth in numeric form SQL

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing a function to pull the dates in the past 12 months. I am thinking to use (Current_date - 1month) for endubg month and (current_date -13months) for the beginning month.

However, when I use Current_date function, it returns me to the value 2022-12-29. Ideally, I would want the value to be 202212 in numeric forms because of my database. Beginning month should be 202112 and the ending month should be 202211. Is there a way I could do this in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `TO_CHAR()` function here:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMM');
```

Comment: Thanks! How do you -13 by month? When I do TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMM')-13, it is showing me 202199 instead of 202112 lol

Comment: Use `ADD_MONTHS`, e.g. `TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -1), 'YYYYMM')`